# Thumbnails on next/previous links in custom post type single.php

Tags: custom-post-types, thumbnails

I've been successful in using the following code to display thumbnails for next & previous links for normal posts but this does not work at all for custom post types.

```
<div id="cooler-nav" class="navigation">
                <?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(true);
                if($prevPost) {?>
                <div class="nav-box previous">
                    <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, 'tiny_thumb' );?>
                    <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
                </div>

                <?php } $nextPost = get_next_post(true);
                if($nextPost) { ?>
                <div class="nav-box next">
                    <?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, 'tiny_thumb' ); } ?>
                    <?php next_post_link('%link',"$nextthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
                </div>
                <?php  ?>
            </div><!--#cooler-nav div -->
```

I'm guessing it must be a special query to look for my custom post type "portfolio"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT

```
<nav class="clearer">

                <?php if( $prev_post = get_previous_post() ): ?>
                    <?php echo $prev_post->ID ?>
                <div class="nav-box previous">
                    <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prev_post->ID, 'tiny_thumb' );?>
                    <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if( $next_post = get_next_post() ): ?>
                    <?php echo $next_post->ID ?>
                    <div class="nav-box next">
                        <?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID, 'tiny_thumb' );  ?>
                        <?php next_post_link('%link',"$nextthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </nav>
```

Other loop not working (I am getting thumbnails & links but no exclusion of current post or randomizing of order)

```
<?php   
                    $t_args = array (
                       'tax_query' => array (
                          array (
                            'orderby' => 'rand',
                            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                            'taxonomy' => 'service',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $service_type,
                            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)

                          )
                       )
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $t_args );

                    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
                       while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                          // output your stuff
                          echo '<div class="more_from_thumb"><a href="';
                          the_permalink();
                          echo '">';
                          the_post_thumbnail();
                          echo '</a></div>';
                       endwhile;
                       wp_reset_query();
                    } ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

The first argument that `get_previous_post` and `get_next_post` is `$in_same_cat`.  WordPress is looking for post of the same type in the current posts category.  If your custom post type doesn't support the `category` taxonomy, both functions are likely to return nothing for the previous and next post.

Try calling both functions without arguments for your custom post type.

```
<?php if( $prev_post = get_previous_post() ): ?>
    <div class="nav-box previous">
        <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prev_post->ID, 'tiny_thumb' );?>
        <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( $next_post = get_next_post() ): ?>
    <div class="nav-box next">
        <?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID, 'tiny_thumb' ); } ?>
        <?php next_post_link('%link',"$nextthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Was just about to say exactly this. The problem lies in the `$in_same_cat`. [See this trac report](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17807)

Comment: Thank you both for replying but I've had a look and cannot make sense of how to get the suggested code working. Not sure what I should & shouldn't place in the "do stuff here". If you could give me a little more detail this would be awesome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the answer now, it includes code in place of `do stuff here`

Comment: Thanks for doing that Christopher but unfortunately nothing is displaying. I added an echo of $prev_post->ID & next post and they are displaying the correct IDs.

I also am experiencing problems with another loop (I've edited my original question to include this bit of code) the problem is that I cannot exclude the existing post OR get a random orderby.